# Why does explorer.exe hang and crash nearly every day?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

Why does explorer.exe hang and crash nearly every day?
I'm using Windows 10 21H1 and it also happened on version 20H2 and 1909.
Looking at Event Viewer doesn't give any significant information or signature about the errors.

It appears to be related to `SearchApp.exe` which works with Windows Search.

Also this started happening on the first day I used my laptop after it was wiped out and reinstalled, and there was no bloatware so it doesn't seem to be due to third party software.

Comment: Also this started happening on the first day I used my laptop after it was wiped out and reinstalled,  <--  One "normal' cause for this is context errors. However, right after a fresh install, that does not fit. Have you tried updating all your drivers - drivers will have been wiped out during reinstall. Check the manufacturer's Driver Update app for new drivers. Check for any optional Windows Updates and run Updates again for .NET Framework updates.

Comment: I have installed the latest version for the drivers, used windows update and installed the various runtime updates like .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 and [Visual C++ Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Comment: That is intriguing. I have put together lots of Windows 10 systems for customers and then also for myself. Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) does not crash on a newly installed system. I will keep looking around.

Comment: Drivers probably have nothing to do with a explorer.exe crash (but *could*).  This is probably one of two things.  #1  Shell extensions.  These are third party "programs" allowed to be added the shell to extend it's functionality.  MANY programs add these.  You will need a tool to figure out what is installed unless you are an expert at using the registry.  #2  Registry corruption.. there are many parts of the reg that the explorer uses to maintain state (like window positions, etc).  Sloppy programming has led to reading in these values without checking boundaries (MS booo).

Comment: Try creating a NEW PROFILE/USER, log in as that and see if the problem persists.  If a new user name/profile doesn't make the problem happen, then it is reg corruption for your other login.  If it DOES still happen, then someone will need to interpret a stack trace to tell you where it is ACTUALLY crashing (any real win32 programmer can do this).

Comment: Find a registry cleaner software . That may check and clean your registry.

Comment: Registry cleaners should **NEVER** be used and they are a **BAD** idea which **CAUSES DAMAGE** to to the computer. Microsoft strongly recommends **against** using them. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-support-policy-for-the-use-of-registry-cleaning-utilities-0485f4df-9520-3691-2461-7b0fd54e8b3a In my opinion such software is scams to scam people who aren't tech savvy for easy money.

Comment: If you have some `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, zip up a couple and post them online for us to analyze.

Comment: Download procdump (Sysinternals) to C:\dumps\ then run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`.  Next time it crashes you should have a dump file in C:\dumps\.  You may get 2 but the first will do. Maybe you can share that.

Comment: Do I have to leave command prompt open?

Comment: The only `.dmp` files I have in the `minidump` folder are for 2 blue screens I had, and any crashes which would appear on Event Monitor or Reliability Monitor, they do not appear in this folder.

Comment: Should I export the relevant `.etl` event viewer files and upload them for you to download?

Comment: @helpinghand I tried your instructions while leaving command prompt open and after it crashed I never got any dump or error log files in the specified folder.

Comment: I have various error logs in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive`

Comment: @HelpingHand The dump files have now been generated eventually. You can download them here. https://mega.nz/folder/JY9SkYjJ#bOWCmwec92fwyF5xO0PLcA

Comment: @harrymc The dump files have now been generated eventually. You can download them here. https://mega.nz/folder/JY9SkYjJ#bOWCmwec92fwyF5xO0PLcA

Comment: With so many applications crashing with memory access violation, something is very wrong here, perhaps hardware. I suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for as long as you can, at least overnight, and post online the HTML report file that it generates. Let me know when finished.

Comment: @harrymc Memtest86 has 15 different tests. Which one should I do? https://www.memtest86.com/tech_individual-test-descr.html

Comment: All of them. Let it loop doing full passes and let it work as many hours as you can, for at least 4 full passes.

Comment: I've fixed the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed. I have solved the problem so now it doesn't happen any more. To fix this recurring issue multiple solutions have to be done.

## Run as adminstrator

The following software which I use should be running as administrator.

- [Discord](https://discord.com) (this also includes Discord PTB or Canary (public test build) if you have that installed)
- [NCH Software Debut](https://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html)
- [Faststone Capture](https://faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm)
- [Faststone Image Viewer](https://faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm)

You will have to decide which software you use has to be run that way, based on the errors, crashes and freezes you often receive on your computer regarding such software. Do NOT do this for your web browser as that is a security hazard for getting viruses.

If you don't know how to find the relevant `.exe` file in `program files` follow these instructions.

1. Search for the software name on the start menu
2. Click open containing folder on the right hand side or right click menu
3. Right click the program name shortcut or click once to select it, then click properties
4. On the shortcut tab, click open file location
5. Right click the program name that launches the program, the `.exe` executable file, then click properties. Or find properties on the ribbon toolbar.
6. On the compatibility tab, tick the `run this program as administrator` checkbox.
7. Once ticked, click OK to save your changes

[image: finding a program in the start menu to open its containing folder]

[image: open containing folder of shortcut]

[image: run this program as administrator change properties of program]

Note that for Debut 4 files will have to undergo this process.

- debut.exe
- debutsetup_vx.exe (where x is the version number)
- debutfilterinstallerx64
- debutfilterinstallerx86

Now that I think of it, because Debut installs a driver to the computer and Windows 10 has a new version every 6 months, I should upgrade Debut as was using a version of Debut dated 31/05/2019 when the latest version was released in 05/07/2021.

## Change the startup type of the Teamviewer service to manual

This is for if you have Teamviewer installed on your computer. If so, then you're going to want to open the Services window.
To open up services, open Run by using **Windows Key + R** then typing in **services.msc** or use the **Windows + X** key then click on **Computer Management**.

[image: services change teamviewer to manual startup type]

## Uninstall buggy software

Uninstall all software made by Wondershare as it slows down the computer as it comes with 2 services that are always running even after you uninstall it. You will have to use Autoruns (see below) to delete the services after uninstalling it.

I also uninstalled VLC and TortoiseSVN as it was causing windows and third party software to crash, not just itself. I also uninstalled Do PDF version 9 as I already had version 11 installed.

I found that Foxit PDF Reader version 9 is buggy so I uninstalled it and got instant improvements so the error happened less. See if you have any buggy software that needs uninstalling. However they did release version 11 which has much less bugs and crashes.

Download [Mini Toolbox](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/minitoolbox/). After running it, tick the `list installed programs` checkbox then click OK.

[image: tick list installed programs on mini toolbox]

After enough waiting a newly created text file will appear in notepad with a list of all the programs you have installed. This file will be saved in the same folder that Mini Toolbox is running from.

[image: minitoolbox list installed programs text file logs]

What you want to do with this information, is to look for any software that is mentioned twice under the same name but with different version numbers. That would show that software didn't uninstall properly and has left traces on your computer. So uninstall the version that doesn't appear on the start menu, then delete traces left behind from the following folders.

- %APPDATA%
- %LOCALAPPDATA%
- Program Files
- Program Files (x86)

If you're having trouble finding out the version number of a software because it won't open or it has no about window or page, you can use the properties window of the `.exe` file to get it. It'll appear under the `details` tab. This does not work for shortcuts that point to an `.exe` file.

[image: version number of exe file shown in properties window]

## Autoruns

[Download Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) then once it's open, click the file menu then the `run as administrator` option and wait for it to finish loading the full list. Make sure that you opened the file that matches your computer architecture like if your computer is 32 bit, 64 bit or using arm processor.

[image: click run as administrator menu option on sysinternals autoruns]

[image: autoruns screenshot]

[image: autoruns scanning progress compared scanning and done ready]

There's 3 things you're going to want to do here.

1. Uncheck all the entries with a missing file or registry key (this will be coloured red or yellow)
2. Go to the `office` tab then uncheck every entry that appears blank (this will be coloured red or yellow)
3. Do the same thing for the `image hijack` tab
4. Uncheck all the startup entries which are related to any software you recently uninstalled
5. Look inside the  **startup**  and  **scheduled tasks**  and uncheck anything there that shouldn't be running at startup.

For me I unchecked the following to run at startup. Adobe sofware, Nova PDF Updater, Foxit PDF Updater, Brave Updater and Microsoft Edge Updater.

There are some dll files which will appear as not found yet should remain kept as the text given is misleading.

[image: autoruns empty known windows dll files in autoruns for xtajit and cpu bit architecture]

## Slow down the speed or throttle your backup software

My disk usage would occasionally go to 99% or 100% and cause third party software to crash. I use [Backblaze](https://backblaze.com) to backup my computer and for my situation I had to move the performance slider to throttle it in the position below.

[image: backblaze changing backup speed]

## Windows Troubleshooters

You need to run the following troubleshooters.

- Search troubleshooter
- Power troubleshooter
- Windows Store Apps troubleshooter

To find the troubleshooters, search for `troubleshoot` on the start menu and click the `troubleshoot settings` option. This can also be found in the system category of windows settings.

[image: open troubleshooting settings on start menu]

At the bottom of the new window that appears, scroll down to the bottom and click `additional troubleshooters`. There you'll find the relevant troubleshooters to run.

[image: open additional troubleshooters link on troubleshooting page]

## Speed up .NET Framework

Run .NET Framework Optimisation Service or `mscorsvw.exe`. [Here's information from microsoft about it.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up/) You will have to [download the file from github](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/tools/DrainNGENQueue/DrainNGenQueue.wsf) called `DrainNGenQueue.wsf`. When you open it, a black window will open that it is supposed to spontaneously close without you being able to read the text that was printed on the screen. That means that the operation completed successfully.

## Windows Explorer Optimisations

Three things have to be done to optimise windows explorer to delete databases which have gone corrupt. Don't worry, what's being reset is nothing major.

Below are the databases which are (or seem) corrupt

- File Explorer History
- Icon Cache
- Thumbnail Cache

You need to open `File Explorer Options`. You can find this by searching for it on the start menu, or using the file explorer (or the file manager), clicking the `view` tab in the ribbon then clicking the `options` icon on the right hand side.

Once clicked, a new window should appear with you viewing the `general` tab. Click the `clear` button then click OK to save your changes.

[image: click the clear button on file explorer settings under the general tab]

Now to clear the icon cache and thumbnail cache. There is an simpler way or a hard way to do this. I'll start with the easy way. The Windows Club has a free software for clearing both the icon cache and thumbnail cache. When you use it make sure that both checkboxes are ticked. [You can download it here.](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/icon-cache-rebuilder-for-windows-10) Or if you prefer you could just use the [command line](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10).

[image: thumbnail and icon cache software program from the windows club]

Now for the hard way, it is typically done with command prompt that should be running as administrator, to then run commands that are typed in using the keyboard on the command line. But it's common for files to be locked so they fail to delete as they're already being used, and closing windows explorer on task manager just makes it open up again. In that case [Hijack This](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/hijackthis/) can be used to make sure that files are deleted upon restarting the computer.

[image: command prompt running as administrator on windows 10]

[image: hijack this main menu click misc miscellaneous tools]

[image: hijack this click the delete file on reboot button on the misc tools page]

---

---

---

Once all these solutions have been done, restart your computer then the problem should be fixed.

## I found a virus on my computer

[image: autoruns image hijacks disable entries for missing files]

[image: 2 viruses in rar file screenshot]

[image: malwarebytes found a virus 1]

[image: flash virus digital certificate]

[image: facebook messenger virus digital certificate]

[[image: autoruns jump to entry on virus]

[image: registry editor right click folder menu]

[image: registry editor screenshot]

You can download [Reg Organiser](https://www.chemtable.com/organizer.htm) here in order to open registry keys to see their structure and contents, **WITHOUT** adding it to your windows registry. Just don't use any cleaners or optimsers as they might be bad and make your computer worse.

[image: reg organiser nowow folder flashcenter key]

[image: reg organiser nowow folder flashhelper key]

[image: reg organiser wow6432 flashcenter key]

[image: reg organiser wow6432 flashservic key]